# How to generate react native Android and ios debug build on Windows without Android studio and Xcode

Tags: react-native

How to generate build for android and iPhone on windows without X code and Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

iOS build is not possible on windows, for android you have to do

```
cd android
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

for release version do `./gradlew assembleRelease`